# Is there common pattern to sychronize access token creation from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, odata, access-token

I have a client to OData system, and it (system) works in following way.

- first I have to send a **special request** to retrieve a **token**.
- then I make my requests, attaching **token** to each request.
- at certain time request may fail, saying that **token** is outdated. then I should make another **special request** to get a new **token**

This is easy when I have only one thread. But I want to have multiple threads doing requests and all sharing the same **token**. Also if more than one concurrent requests fail with **token** being invalidated I want to send a **special request** exactly once and other clients to start using the updated **token**.

If it matters I am using C#.

Is there a common solution to synchronize such requests?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much more about your implementation, one option could be [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx).

Your threads could check the cache for a specific 'tokenkey' and get its value.  You can set a expiration in your MemoryCache ahead of a known expiration if you wanted to prevent 401s or other unauthorized results.

Here's an example I use to get/set a new token required for auth header in web api calls:

```
private string GetNewToken()
{
    lock (cacheLock)
    {
        // no token in cache so go get a new one
        var newToken = TokenServiceAgent.GetJwt();

        // number of minutes (offset) before JWT expires that will trigger update of cache 
        var cacheLifetime = 15

        CacheItemPolicy cip = new CacheItemPolicy()
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheLifetime.Value))
        };

        MemoryCache.Default.Set("tokenkey", newToken, cip);

        return newToken;
    }
}
```

EDIT: can't get the code block to play nice in the SO editor